# ajax $.post function after native form submission

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, form-submit

I'm trying to natively submit a form using the code below:

```
$('#invoices-bundle').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit multiple times
    this.submit();
    $.post('php/seller/invoice/invoice_print_batch.php', function(data){
        $('#added-invoices').html(data);                                             
    });// use the native submit method of the form element   
});
```

After the submit(); I want to populate the DOM with the contents of my PHP script. The weird thins is the DOM doesn't get populated the first time I submit the form but the second time and everytime after that.

Don't know why this happens! Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Your approach looks weird to me. After you 'natively' submit the form (i.e. non-Ajax) you are making an Ajax call to the server and using that response! You need to understand that once you make the browser send a non-Ajax request to server, then the browser's nature is to wait for its response. Once it gets it, it will replace the current page with whatever is in that response. So your current page and DOM states are gone. You should not be doing stuffs after `this.submit()`. If it takes too long for submit to respond then the code below it will get the chance to execute, else, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you submit form with  `this.submit();`, the rest of the codes will be useless. The page gonna be change or refresh and after ajax codes will be break. Make form to post as ajax, instead of regular form submit or change the order of codes, put `submit()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit via AJAX then why are you including a comment to 'use the native submit' (which seems conflicted with your prevent default)?

It seems as though you would *not* need to execute a submit action when you are executing the AJAX post -- which executes right away; are you hoping to gather up the POST return values and make them available to your invoice_print_batch.php page? Are there form elements on the page that need to get sent along as well? Populate those variables and send them in the data parameter of your `$.post` call.

```
$('#invoices-bundle').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit multiple times
    var itemToSend = form.find('input[name="inputsName"]').val();
    // ...more?
    $.post('invoice_print_batch.php', { value: itemToSend }, function(data) {
        $('#added-invoices').html(data);
    });
});
```

Here, `value` will be in your $_POST for invoice_print_batch.php.

The form's natural submit has been avoided, the values on your page have been sent to your php page, and the results of that php POST can get updated on your current page.

If your real page processing happens on the current page, you might want to move the processing into the invoice_print_batch.php -- perhaps rename that file -- and have that page process all the form input and return / print the 'answer'. The end result would be a page that felt more responsive without any page loading / redirecting to process the submit.

Did you need to have the full path? I shortened it for readability's sake which you can do if the current page is in the same directory -- which it might not be.